# Formulating a 3D "twist" transformation for a unit circle into a lemniscate while preserving arc length

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

I'm exploring the transformation of a 2D unit circle into a lemniscate (infinity symbol) by fixing two antipodal points and "twisting" the circle (in the 3rd dimension) such that the orthogonal pair of antipodal points meet at the origin. The total perimeter length $2\pi$ should be preserved during the transformation.

The unit circle in the $xy$-plane is described by:

$$
x = \cos(\theta),
y = \sin(\theta),
z = 0,
$$

where $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$.

I seek an exact mathematical formulation for this transformation. The primary challenge is in defining the function for the $z$-coordinate, $f(\theta)$, which should modify the curve's height without changing its length.

I would appreciate any advice, references, or ideas on how to approach this.

Comment: The space curve has variable  curvature and torsion with right angled self intersections at  the origin, right?

Comment: @Narasimham - The intersection point need not necessarily be at right angles

Answer (score 2):

Such a transformation can be written down fairly straightforwardly, except that the requirement to keep the length constant introduces a somewhat implicit element:
$$
x=\cos \theta \ , \ y=\sin \theta \cos t \ , \ z=a(t) \sin \theta \cos \theta \sin t
$$
where $\theta \in [0,2\pi ]$, and $t\in [0,\pi /2]$ is the deformation parameter; at $t=0$, one has the circle, at $t=\pi /2$, one has the lemniscate. The function $a(t)$ varies monotonically between $a(0)=1$ and $a(\pi/2)=1.061395$; it is defined by the requirement of constant length at any given $t$,
$$
2\pi =\int_{0}^{2\pi } d\theta \sqrt{1+(a^2 \cos^2 2\theta - \cos^2 \theta ) \sin^{2} t}
$$
and can be easily determined numerically.

Comment: This puts the lemniscate orthogonal to the circle — in the $xz$ plane, as opposed to the $xy$ plane the original circle is in. I think OP is looking for a $180^\circ$ twist. (Though I suppose composing this with a rotation of $t$ about the x axis will do it.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki - I chose the most symmetric arrangement, which indeed places the final curve into the $xz$ plane. From what I can see, the OP expressed no preference in this respect. Certainly, one can straightforwardly compose this with a rotation about the $x$ axis such as to place the final curve back in the $xy$ plane.

Comment: If the space curve is entirely in the $xy$ plane then it has  no torsion anywhere , has curvature only, so is like a Bernoulli Lemniscate... ( length to be adjusted $2\pi$ ) right?

Comment: @Narasimham - well, at the intersection point, the curvature vanishes and the direction of the binormal vector flips, for both of the line segments present there. Together, these are equal in magnitude, opposite in sign effects. In the rest of the figure, indeed, there trivially can be no torsion. The particular lemniscate I parametrized here is just a Lissajous figure - apparently also known as the lemniscate of Gerono.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt  Is there a transformation that gives a Bernoulli Lemniscate?

Comment: Ah, I see, ok. The problem is in mechanics of materials I suppose in shape finding of an Elastic ring ( maybe of rectangular section, moments of inertia ratio of $I_x/I_y$ ) when antipodal points are squeezed together. Static equilibrium, moment/curvature & torque/torsion relations, material elastic constants formulate an ode, which when integrated define its bending/twisting elastic deformations.

Comment: @swami - sure, you can do the same thing with a Bernoulli lemniscate, just all the expressions become longer, because you have an additional $\theta $-dependent denominator in the parametrization.